# Python: Splitting words in text file into limited 40 characters AND filling the extra "slot" with spaces

Tags: python, string, split, append, character

first time posting in stackoverflow! I'm a newbie at coding in general, but is interested. Would love some insights and improvement on my script. And I need help:

As the title states, I'm working on a script that

- Reads a text file
- Split the words in the file into strings/list
- Append the words into one line with 40 limited character space (if a word does not finish as the limit is reached, the string will only take until the last "space"/break)
- If the string is cut into say 36 characters, the 4 remaining characters should be "space"

I've managed to get things done until the third point(with help from this site of course!), but I need help on the last one; padding the string with "spaces" to complete a 40 characters string per line.

Below are my script so far:

```
import sys

file = open("read_me2.txt", "r+")
text = file.read()

def split_string (text, limit, sep= " "):

    words = text.split()
    if max(map(len,words)) > limit:
        raise ValueError("limit is too small")
    res = []
    part = words[0]
    others = words[1:]
    for word in others: 
        if len(sep)+len(word) > limit-len(part):
            res.append(part)
            part = word              

        else:
            part +=sep+word

    if part:
        res.append(part)

    return res

print(split_string(text=text, limit=40))
```

Here is what the read_me2.txt contains:

> Okay this is a test to see if it can cut the number of characters to 40 and then separate it based on the existence of spaces and what not. I think this is more than 40 characters. Shall we try it?

And here's what I have so far as output:

> ['Okay this is a test to see if it can cut', 'the number of characters to 40 and then', 'separate it based on the existence of', 'spaces and what not. I think this is', 'more than 40 characters. Shall we try', 'it?']

As you can see, some of the lines have less than 40 characters. Those should be appended with spaces until the 40th character.
 Help and advice(if there's a cleaner or better way to do my script) is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following:

```
def pad(line, limit):
    return line + " " * (limit-len(line))

def split_string (text, limit, sep= " "):

    words = text.split()
    if max(map(len,words)) > limit:
        raise ValueError("limit is too small")
    res = []
    part = words[0]
    others = words[1:]
    for word in others:
        if len(sep)+len(word) > limit-len(part):
            res.append(part)
            part = word

        else:
            part +=sep+word

    if part:
        res.append(part)

    result = [pad(l, limit) for l in res]
    return result
```

Comment: Although it says avoid commenting with thanks, I wanted to thank you. Works like a charm. I should've went with another function like that. Thanks! I'll keep that in mind the next time I progress.